# I am trying to create dynamic table into existing database in SQL-Server by using C#.NET console Application. But i getting exception

Tags: c#, sql, database

**here is exception**

An unhandled exception of type **'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException** occurred in **System.Data.dll**

**Additional information:**
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
**my code is here**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace AdoDemo
{
   class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       Program p = new Program();
       p.CreateTable();
     }
     public void CreateTable()
     {
       SqlConnection con = null;
       con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=MYDB; integrated security=SSPI");
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("create table STUDENT(ID int,SNAME varchar(10),MOBILE 
       bigint)",con);
       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       Console.WriteLine("Table created successfully..");
       con.Close();    
      }
    }
}
```

[This is myCode Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SmsG.png)

Comment: Depending on the version of Sql Server you’re using, you could be missing an instance name on your “Data Source” parameter. E.g. data source = .\SQLEXPRESS vs data source = . , should match whatever appears on the server drop down when you launch SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the connection string:

```
con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=MYDB; integrated security=SSPI")
```

You need something like that:

```
    Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

You have missed: Data Source, User ID and Password